In typescript , need to write alternate code for my use case , to avoid 'new Function()' and 'eval()' , to bypass security issues
I have a json  like eg: context = {ten:10, nine: 9, level1:{level2: 'test'}}
need to verify a condition inside a string like "context.ten > 9".
I was using a new Function() to execute this. They were security vulnerability issues raised for our repository.  I had to remove that, tried to write my own alternate code. The code seems to be failing for some of the test cases.
Some of the sample input strings are in the format.
"context.ten === 10", "context.level1.level2 === 'test'", "context.inCorrect.level2 == 'test'". It will raise error for last case. I had tried to cover every possible case.
But we started seeing inputs like "!!context.id" which should give undefined error, unable to handle for "!!" or "&&". Earlier with new Function(), conveniently we were able to execute every possible case.
It looks like we may get any kind of an input, but "context" will definitely be present in the input string. It is always going to be a conditional operator.
Any suggestions or directions would be of great help. I wanted to share my code, but I think it is all over the place.

testString.split(/\s*===?\s*) should get you halfway there...

Instead of sharing code that's all over the place or not sharing code at all, you should consider making a [mre] that demonstrates the gist of your issue so that others could possibly test any solution they suggest. Right now with the information you have, I'd say the answer is one of the following three general approaches: • You trust your inputs so push back on whoever was reporting it as a vulnerability • You don't trust your inputs so write your own full-fledged sandboxed JS parser • You don't trust your inputs so stop parsing strings and change to a data structure.

(see prev comment) without a [mre] or more details it's impossible to say which makes sense for your use cases.

The fundamental issue here seems to be that you allow arbitrary code to be executed, you want to change this to not be arbitrary code execution, but also your requirement is for the new approach to allow arbitrary code execution. You can't really have that. The secure way of doing it is defining a limited set of operations possible - anything else should not be allowed. This doesn't work if you don't actually know what inputs you have or would have because you should be driving this.
